# Enable Cypress' be.disabled check on custom angular component

Tags: cypress

On a custom Angular component that implements `ControlValueAccessor`, what do I need to do so that I can check for `cy.get('...').should('be.disabled')`

I tried placing this in the component:

```js
@HostBinding('attr.disabled')
protected disabled = false
```

and when the Cypress test runs, it shows my match like so:

```html
<app-boolean-select-with-tooltip _ngcontent-a-c144="" data-cy="second" class="half ng-untouched ng-pristine" _nghost-a-c145="" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]" ng-reflect-label="x" disabled="true">
```

which has the `disabled="true"` attribute showing, but the `.should('be.disabled')` for that times out with an AssertionError.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's limited to Angular custom element, it would be the same with a `<div>` for example.

You can check for the presence of any attribute with `have.attr` assertion

```js
cy.get('app-boolean-select-with-tooltip')
  .should('have.attr', 'disabled')
```

The [HTML attribute: disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) attribute normally doesn't take a value, which is probably why `.should('be.disabled')` is not working.

**Correction** - `.should('be.disabled')` should work accrding to the brief documentation, I think it's a bug.

Ref [Disability](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements#Disability)

> Cypress checks whether an element's `disabled` property is true.